# Eigen with custom scalar types: Matrix multiplication with custom type fails with `use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous`

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to integrate `boost.units` into `Eigen`, following the  [official documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html). I've also looked at two projects that have done the same, and I've tested the operation with their code as well, although I'm getting the same error ([Project 1](https://github.com/westernmagic/eigen-boost-units) [Project 2](https://github.com/iastate-robotics/eigen3-units)).

The issues I am having is that there seems to be some ambiguity regarding the multiplication operator when multiplying two matrices with custom scalar types based on `boost::units`.

This behaviour occurs with `clang` 10.0.0.3 and Apple `clang`  11.0.3.

The code that triggers the error (`use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous`) is the following:

```
    const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>, 2, 3> x;
    const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::dimensionless, double>, 3, 1> y;
    const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>, 2, 1> result = x * y;
```

For the integration I created files containing `NumTraits` for `boost::units::quantity<T>` as follows:

```
namespace Eigen {

template<class T> struct NumTraits<boost::units::quantity<T>> : NumTraits<double> {
    typedef boost::units::quantity<T> Real;
    typedef boost::units::quantity<T> NonInteger;
    typedef boost::units::quantity<T> Nested;

    enum {
        IsComplex             = 0,
        IsInteger             = 0,
        IsSigned              = 1,
        RequireInitialization = 1,
        ReadCost              = 1,
        AddCost               = 3,
        MulCost               = 3
    };
};
} // namespace Eigen
```

And for the multiplication support I have the following `struct` definitions:

```
namespace Eigen {

namespace units = boost::units;

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB,
    internal::scalar_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB>> {
    typedef units::quantity<typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type> ReturnType;
};

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
    internal::scalar_product_op<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
    typedef units::quantity<typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type> ReturnType;
};

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
    internal::scalar_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>, units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
    typedef units::quantity<typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type> ReturnType;
};

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB,
    internal::scalar_conj_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB>> {
    typedef typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type ReturnType;
};

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
    internal::scalar_conj_product_op<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
    typedef typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type ReturnType;
};

template<typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<units::quantity<scalarA>, units::quantity<scalarB>,
    internal::scalar_conj_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>, units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
    typedef units::quantity<typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type> ReturnType;
};

} // namespace Eigen
```

The full error output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target LaserCalibration
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LaserCalibration.dir/maths/Maths.cpp.o
/Users/dwright/projects/dv-laser-calibration/maths/Maths.cpp:9:97: error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous (with operand types 'const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>, 2, 3>' (aka 'const Matrix<quantity<unit<list<dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, static_rational<1> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, homogeneous_system<list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, static_rational<3> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > > >, double>, 2, 3>') and 'const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::dimensionless, double>, 3, 1>' (aka 'const Matrix<quantity<unit<boost::units::dimensionless_type, homogeneous_system<list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, static_rational<3> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > > >, double>, 3, 1>'))
        const Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>, 2, 1> result = x * y;
                                                                                                     ~ ^ ~
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/CommonCwiseBinaryOps.h:50:29: note: candidate function [with T = Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::length_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1, 1> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, static_rational<3> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > >, void>, double>, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3>]
EIGEN_MAKE_SCALAR_BINARY_OP(operator*,product)
                            ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/CommonCwiseBinaryOps.h:50:29: note: candidate function [with T = Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::dimensionless_type, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, static_rational<3> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > >, void>, double>, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>]
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:166:5: note: candidate function [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::dimensionless_type, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10, static_rational<3> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > >, void>, double>, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>]
    operator*(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived> &other) const;
    ^
/Users/dwright/projects/dv-laser-calibration/maths/Maths.cpp:6:106: warning: unused parameter 'event' [-Wunused-parameter]
Eigen::Matrix<boost::units::quantity<double>, 2, 1> Maths::convertToPhysicalCoordinates(const dv::Event &event) const {
                                                                                                         ^
In file included from /Users/dwright/projects/dv-laser-calibration/maths/Maths.cpp:1:
/Users/dwright/projects/dv-laser-calibration/maths/Maths.hpp:16:25: warning: private field 'parameters' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
        CalibrationParameters &parameters;
                               ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/LaserCalibration.dir/maths/Maths.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/LaserCalibration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
11:04:41: The process "/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project LaserCalibration (kit: Imported Kit)
When executing step "CMake Build"
11:04:41: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the conjugate product traits, I can see that the third specialization seems off:

```
template <typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
    struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<
    scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
    internal::scalar_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>,
    units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
        typedef units::quantity<
            typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type>
            ReturnType;
    };
```

The line:

```
    scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
```

Ought to read:

```
    units::quantity<scalarA>, units::quantity<scalarB>,
```

### Eliminating the cause

That third specialization we just fixed should obviously be the one matching our case. However, the other specializations do not exclude the case where both scalars are a quantity.

Commenting out the irrelevant two indeed makes things pass:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eGRtHB)**

```
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <boost/units/limits.hpp>
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/cmath.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Core>

namespace Eigen {
    namespace units = boost::units;

#if 0
    template <typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
        struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<
        units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB,
        internal::scalar_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>, scalarB>> {
            typedef units::quantity<
                typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type>
                ReturnType;
        };
#endif

#if 0
    template <typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
        struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<
        scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>,
        internal::scalar_product_op<scalarA, units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
            typedef units::quantity<
                typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type>
                ReturnType;
        };
#endif

#if 1
    template <typename scalarA, typename scalarB>
        struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<
        units::quantity<scalarA>, units::quantity<scalarB>,
        internal::scalar_product_op<units::quantity<scalarA>,
        units::quantity<scalarB>>> {
            typedef units::quantity<
                typename units::multiply_typeof_helper<scalarA, scalarB>::type>
                ReturnType;
        };
#endif
} // namespace Eigen

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using V = boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length, double>;
    using U = boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::dimensionless, double>;
    constexpr auto Vu = boost::units::si::meter;
    constexpr auto Uu = 1.0;

    Eigen::Matrix<V, 2, 3> x;
    Eigen::Matrix<U, 3, 1> y;

    x << 1*Vu, 2*Vu, 3*Vu, 4*Vu, 5*Vu, 6*Vu;
    y << 1*Uu, 2*Uu, 3*Uu;

    std::cout << "x:\n" << x << "\n";
    std::cout << "y:\n" << y << "\n";
    auto result = (x * y).eval();

    std::cout << "result:\n" << result << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
x:
  1 m   2 m   3 m
  4 m   5 m   6 m
y:
              1 dimensionless
              2 dimensionless
              3 dimensionless
result:
  14 m
  32 m
```

### FIX?

I would try to combine all three in a single specializatio. However `ScalarBinaryOpTraits` is not SFINAE-friendly. I tried to get something going nonetheless:

```
namespace Eigen {
    namespace units = boost::units;

    namespace /*file-static*/ {
        template <typename A, typename B, typename R = units::multiply_typeof_helper<A, B> >
        struct QuantityProductImpl {
            using ReturnType = typename R::type;
        };
    }

    template <typename A, typename B>
        struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<A, B,
            std::enable_if_t< units::is_quantity<A>::value && units::is_quantity<B>::value,
                internal::scalar_product_op<A, B>
            >
        > : QuantityProductImpl<A, B> { };
} // namespace Eigen
```

Which does work like earlier: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/HX86re)**

However, if we change the `&&` into `||` (or `!=` for XOR logic) we get ambiguity again. Not sure how to proceed, but maybe it gives you ideas?

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed my mistake! I will look further into your suggestion on the combination into a single specialization.